# Need to automate Sending Telegram Messages for the next 14 Days

Tags: automation, telegram, scheduling

I have a Telegram Group that I recreate every 2 weeks. I then have a list of messages & media that need to be sent at certain times in the next 2 weeks. I am using Telegram's "Schedule Message" that I set up on the first Sunday evening. I am looking for a way to automate this whereby I have a sheet that has the details & it can be read & posted into the group... Something like this

1. 06/02/2022 8:00pm "Message1...."
2. 07/02/2022 9:00am Pic1
3. 07/02/2022 10:00am Pic2
4. 07/02/2022 10:30am "Message2....."

Any ideas how I can automate this? Instead of doing this every 2 weeks manually.

Answer (score 1):

use telethon! it's as easy as doing:
`pip install telethon`

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message here you can find the part about scheduling :)